# Is there a way to get the data being dropped in DropTargetListener.dragEnter()?

Tags: eclipse, drag-and-drop, eclipse-plugin

I'm using [ViewerDropAdapter](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ViewerDropAdapter.html) to handle data dropped in a viewer.
There is no direct way to access [DropTargetEvent](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/dnd/DropTargetEvent.html).data field in its [validateDrop](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ViewerDropAdapter.html#validateDrop%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20org.eclipse.swt.dnd.TransferData%29) method. 
This  field seems to be null in all event handlers of DropListener and is only filled in [DropTargetListener.drop()](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/dnd/DropTargetListener.html#drop%28org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTargetEvent%29).
This makes it impossible to reject the data viewer doesn't like on earlier stages of DND sequence like [dragEnter()](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/dnd/DropTargetListener.html#dragEnter%28org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTargetEvent%29).

Can DND framework be queried for the data before the actual drop?

A custom [Transfer](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/dnd/Transfer.html) could probably solve this problem, but is it appropriate to use it as data filter, not just a converter?

Comment: `ViewDropAdapter` does have a `getCurrentEvent` method returning the `DropTargetEvent` which can be called during `validateDrop`

Comment: @greg-449 event contains no data if you try to access it outside of final drop handler.

Answer (score 0):

getCurrentEvent().item will give you the item on which you drop

getSelectedObject() will give you the item that is being dragged.

You can use those in your validateDrop method of ViewDropAdapter to either allow the drop or disallow it.